# NetBeans Change Method Parameters refactor - No Types Found

Tags: java, netbeans

NetBeans has a refactoring option to change method parameters, which would be useful.

However, when I click on one of the existing parameters to change its type, it says No Types Found, as though it didn't recognize the existing parameter type (even though javac is perfectly happy with it) and the error message remains unchanged no matter what I change the parameter type to.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You still have to type the requested type name!
[image]